# Android: Cache storage location for PWA using com.google.androidbrowserhelper.trusted.LauncherActivity

Tags: android, caching, service-worker, trusted-web-activity

My PWA is bundled in an Android App using `com.google.androidbrowserhelper.trusted.LauncherActivity`. My service worker is able to manage the cache as expected.

Question is: Where is the data actually stored?

I tried to remove/reinstall the app, I also cleared cache and data of the app, of the preinstalled "Browser" (LineageOS), the "Android System WebView", as well as other Browsers (Firefox), but the cached elements are still present in the ServiceWorkers cache.